# Access View of Preference in onPreferenceChange

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to access the value of my `SeekBarPreference` in `OnPreferenceChange`.

Here is my listener:

```
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference?, newValue: Any?): Boolean {
        when (preference?.key){
            "my_seekbar_key" -> {
                Log.d(TAG, newValue.toString()) 
                // get View of preference value
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

xml

```
<SeekBarPreference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_widget_seekbar_override"
    app:showSeekBarValue="true"
    android:max="30"
    android:defaultValue="10"
    android:key="my_seekbar_key"
    android:title="Title"/>
```

How can I access the current value of the seekbar value `View`? Because I'd like to change 30 to 3.0, 25 to 2.5 etc